# Moderator deleted my answers, but they were on point

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

Even after reading the FAQ, I don't understand why two of my answers were deleted by the moderator (Bill the Lizard).  The answers were directly on point and offered a useful solution to the question.

[Detecting when the 'back' button is pressed on a navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228411/detecting-when-the-back-button-is-pressed-on-a-navbar)

[Setting action for back button in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214965/setting-action-for-back-button-in-navigation-controller)

How do I ask for reconsideration?

Comment: Were you copy and pasting it to multiple questions?

Comment: You seem to have a habit of giving [the same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117717/when-using-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-i-want-the-tab-bar-to-reappear-when-i-push/14744463#14744463) [more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266026/how-to-use-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-if-i-want-to-hide-the-tabbar-for-only-one-ki/14744421#14744421). If both questions can have exactly the same answer, consider flagging one of them as a duplicate instead.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "habit," not like picking my nails.  It's that when I've looked for an answer to a problem, and finding people with the same question but no working solution, later, when I've fond a solution I'll go back to those similar/exact questions and post what I found that worked.  I thought that would be useful.

Comment: @Jeff It's very useful. But we don't like duplicates. So if you found an answer and several questions which benefit from it, just mark them as duplicates. This will ultimately lead everybody to your single answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please dont duplicate your answer

> What happen when i give exact same answer ?

if answer is exact same it will automatically flag and appear in 10k tool and only one conical answer(for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954425/1723893)) will be there other will will be deleted

> what should i do when both/more question are exact same ?

if you have 3k rep than close as duplicate otherwise flag as Mr. @Bart is telling

and its not first time you have dup your answer i can see other also like

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266026/how-to-use-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-if-i-want-to-hide-the-tabbar-for-only-one-ki/14744421#14744421) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117717/when-using-hidesbottombarwhenpushed-i-want-the-tab-bar-to-reappear-when-i-push/14744463#14744463)

Comment: Yes, I did post my answer to three questions, and two were deleted.  So, I guess I should flag those two as dups.  I haven't done that in the past because the dup questions often have different (valid) answers.  Can I make a new answer with a link to my first post?

Comment: @Jeff just make sure that  wont be link only answer however imo closing as duplicate  would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit split on this kind of thing.  We routinely get notified of copypaste answers (which are often of low quality or spam), but yours definitely were an attempt to answer the question.

Part of the reason why I'm split is that we have a love/hate relationship with dupes.  While I and others have decided to [stop worrying and love dupes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/), others see duplicate questions as the devil trying to, like, make out with their moms, or something.  I dunno.

*Consequently*, while I think that copypasted answers that roughly fit the question are OK, others believe that this is an indication that you should NOT have answered the question, but that you should have flagged the question as a dupe.  Your answer should have been added once to the question you believed was best asked (the "canonical" question).

To those people I say **Feh**.  And, considering recent ongoing changes to duplicate handling, I think the Feh side is winning (oh, how I long for no more "possible dupe" flags!).

I **strongly suggest** you go through your deleted duplicate answers, edit them so that they more directly answer the question (and is not just a copypaste), and flag to have them undeleted.  This will satisfy *everybody*.  Except you, who has to deal with all of this.

Comment: Thank you for the support.  I'm satisfied now since moderator Shog9 merged the duplicates, transferred some of the best answers (mine and others) and basically life is good again.  In the future I'll post, flag, link, and edit according to the various suggestions above.